# Browser resizing when the monitor turns on/off?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, browser

The last week or so I have noticed an odd thing. When I turn on my monitor, my browser windows are all half the size they were when I turned it off. Sometimes when I turn it on the taskbar is even half way up the screen for a few moments, as if turning the monitor on and off was forcing it to change the resolution. I use firefox, running windows 7.

Comment: Stupid question, but bears asking: you've rebooted in the last week or so, yes?

Comment: Do you have multiple monitors?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are physically turning the monitor off instead of just letting it go to sleep normally via power settings?

Comment: No, just one monitor.  I reboot every other day or so.  As for why I turn the monitor off - no reason really, the power settings are set to stay on always, never sleep and I've never bothered to change it.  Its been that way for months though and never caused a problem.

Comment: Did you install any monitor software? What are your monitor specs?

Answer (score 0):

The task bar being halfway up the screen is monitor self adjusting, this is normal. Other then that, try restarting.

Comment: I reboot every other day or so, and this problem has been happening for over a week now

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you may try this freeware (Autosizer) to force the size of any open program :
http://www.southbaypc.com/autosizer/
Hope this help ;)